# How to encode and impute categorical data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, encode, categorical-data

I have a column with categorical data and some nan values. I want to fill nan values rather then drop them. I don't really know what to do at first - encode or impute? I try to encode firstly with LabelEncoder and next impute with KNNImputer but it does not work for me. At the end I want to use OneHotEncoder to get values in proper form to use them as input to ML models. I started with something like this but it is wrong :(

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer

data = ["coupe", "coupe", "SUV", "coupe", "SUV", "sedan", np.nan, "sedan", np.nan, "coupe"]
X = pd.DataFrame({"type": data})
le = LabelEncoder()
X = le.fit_transform(X)
```

I do not know how to deal with this issue:

1. Encode (LabelEncoder)-->Impute (KNNImputer)  -->OneHotEncoder
2. Impute (KNNImputer)  -->Encode (LabelEncoder)-->OneHotEncoder

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`LabelEncoder` raises a `TypeError` if used with `np.nan`s.
Replace them with a dummy string first. And once it's label encoded, replace the label corresponding to the null values back to `np.nan` and this is when you apply `KNNImputer`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer

data = ["coupe", "coupe", "SUV", "coupe", "SUV", "sedan", np.nan, "sedan", np.nan, "coupe"]
X = pd.DataFrame({"type": data})
X[X["type"]  == np.nan] = 'NaN'
le = LabelEncoder()
X = le.fit_transform(X)
#Check the label corresponding to 'NaN' and replace back to `np.nan`
X[X["type"]  == <LabelOfNaN>] = np.nan
#Apply KNNImputer
```